# How to handle ews hang?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exchangewebservices

Sometimes it hangs when you receive email, and because of this, the whole program hangs, how can I check is service hang?

```
ExchangeService service = new Sender().GetService(sourceEmail);
SearchFilter filter = new 
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
ItemView view = new ItemView(20) { PropertySet = PropertySet.IdOnly };
if (oldest) view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,SortDirection.Ascending);
FolderId sharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sourceEmail);

/* hangs on this call */
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(sharedMailbox, filter, view);
```

Comment: does this code throw an exception? which, on which line? or is it just blocking indefinitely - which call?

Comment: @dlatikay last row, when i trying to find items

Comment: @dlatikay no exceptions, only hanging.

Comment: @dlatikay I ask how I can cope with this hang, how to understand in the program that it is frozen. If he gave me an exception, I would not write here.

Comment: so we know now that the `FindItems` call hangs indefinitely. that is unusual, because it is supposed to time out. any odds that somewhere else in that code, the timeout is set to infinite? I would suggest a webservice/network trace, the EWS communication uses web service communication internally. of course if you want to accept the hang, and still continue with execution, you could spawn a thread which you abort after a time (roll-your-own timeout)

Comment: Is your service object being set correctly when you debug? it might be helpful to post your `GetService` code

Comment: @MadDev
`
public ExchangeService GetService(string email)
{
 ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DispatcherCredentials.DefaultCredentials))
 {
  if (DefaultCredentials == "true") IsTest = false;
                else if (DefaultCredentials == "false") IsTest = true;
 }

 if (IsTest)
 {
  service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(EWSLogin,EWSPassword, EWSDomain);
 }
 else
  service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

 service.Url = new Uri("");
 return service;
}`

Comment: @MadDev Everything works correctly for many hours, but sometimes freezing in FindItems

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where FindItems did hang,

It seems to have been related to that I had a StreamingSubscriptionConnection object that I didn't close.